# name of form input causes errors

Tags: html, forms, input

I have never seen this, have no idea what is going on:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/Lib.exe" method=POST name="slider" ID="Form2">
<input type="text" name="user" value="" ID="Text1">
<input type="text" name="end" value="" ID="Text2">
</form>

function setval()
{   
    alert(s.getValue());
    alert(s2.getValue());
    document.slider.user.value = s.getValue();//set value of hidden text box to value of slider
    document.slider.end.value = s2.getValue();//set value of hidden text box to value of slider
    document.slider.submit();
}
```

When submitting form from setval(), when I change the name of the first input box from "user" to anything else, my cgi application won't except it and I get an error? I can change the name of the secons input box to anyting and it doesn't seem to have any problem? Confused. Thanks!

Comment: Where does the error occur?  On the client side (i.e. in the browser) or server side (in your cgi application?)

Comment: Thanks guys, it was a cgi error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems more like it's a problem with the cgi than it is with the HTML/Javascript, to me. It probably makes the assumption that a value for "user" will always be sent. Not much else I can tell you without seeing the form-processing code.

Answer (score 1):

Your CGI must be expecting an element called 'user'. You would need to check the source.